# Have Visual Studio Code show a preview of the file to be opened from Ctrl+P

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to have Visual Studio Code show a preview of the file to be opened from Ctrl+P when I navigate over the suggestions list with the arrow keys?

I expect to see the file I navigate over in Ctrl+P in the editor below. Sublime Text has this.

Answer (score 0):

Not implemented yet.

See open PR [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/8939)